# Assembler exercises

Tags: assembly

I simply love programming and I'm learning many programming languages. I am really interested in assembly language (intel's) but I can't find any exercise around. I know invented ones are the best, but I'm not very imaginative. Can any of you help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will be good to have a premade example to compare your efforts with.

The Atlas library is full of short but well documented assembly routines that implement the BLAS maths routines: http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net.

You can even try to extend the library to include more LAPLACK functions...
Then your code will be usefull too.

Tom

Comment: well, I'm not that good, but I'll give an eye anyway.. after all, everything is useful when learning.. =)

Answer (score 1):

[Adam's x86 assembler tutorial?](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/15526/download.aspx)

Good luck!

**Edit**: Ah, I didn't see you asked for 'exercises'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the wonderful, and now free, art of assembly.

Comment: I've read it, it's a very good book..